# Combination of [spring] DefaultShutdownStrategy, [camel] ShutdownAware and [camel] Processor doesn't works

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, application-shutdown

I have camel `Processor` which is starting `Thread`
this `Processor` implementing spring `ShutdownAware` 
When I send `TERM` signal (graceful shutdown) to application I do not receive any information about - any method from `ShutdownAware` interface were called.
I mentioned about `Thread` because I want to stop it correctly.

```
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.spi.ShutdownAware;

public class MyProcessor implements Processor, ShutdownAware {
...
}
```

Should I register this Processor|ShutdownAware somehow or what?

Answer (score 2):

Solution is:

```
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.Service;
import org.apache.camel.spi.ShutdownAware;

public class MyProcessor implements Processor, ShutdownAware, Service {
...
}
```

then methods from `ShutdownAware` will be called during shutdown even `start()`, `stop()` methods from 'Service' interface are not used.

Answer (score 1):

`ShutdownAware` is a Camel interface, not Spring.

If `MyProcessor` is a Spring bean then it could implement `DisposableBean`, or have a `@PreDestroy` method, or otherwise annotated with something that Spring understands to call when the context is shutting down.

If you're using XML, you might do this

```
<bean class="...MyProcessor" destroy-method="shutdown"/>
```

If you're using `@Bean` perhaps

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public MyProcessor myProcessor() { ... }
```

Of course `MyProcessor` will need a `shutdown` method; nothing in `ShutdownAware` seems suitable.

How is the Spring context created? Perhaps you need to register the shutdown hook, eg: `context.registerShutdownHook();` See the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#registerShutdownHook--)

Really, the way to deal with this is to have the `CamelContext` be aware that Spring is shutting down. That should then inform your processors.

Comment: Yes our you can extend `ServiceSupport` or implement `Service` in your `Processor` class and then Camel will invoke the `doStart` / `doStop` methods as part of the lifecycle on start/stopping. See more at: http://camel.apache.org/lifecycle

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Then what for is `ShutdownAware` / how to use it?

Comment: The javadoc for `ShutdownAware` says this is mainly for in-memory consumers to be provided an chance to ensure their pending exchanges are not lost during shutdown. See https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spi/ShutdownAware.html

Comment: OK, I see. Looks like everything is fine when I add `Service` interface tin my code.